# Can an original image of the god Anubis on a t-shirt infringe trademark or copyright?

Tags: copyright, trademark, public-domain, innocent-infringement

I sell t-shirts online. One of them features a picture of the ancient Egyptian god Anubis (my original art). Some people who viewed it said Anubis is a trademarked for clothing and I may be infringing. Can this be true? I'm not using anyone's logo or claiming a brand name. I would like to think I'm referencing ancient mythology and nobody can contest that, but I now have a nagging doubt and don't want any legal trouble.

Edit. - To further clarify, soneone has shown me on the WIPO database that there is a word trademark on "Anubis" under section 25 clothing.
So I don't think the image could infringe. But if I list the t-shirt as Anubis t-shirt, would that infringe trademark. I really want to be able to list with the name Anubis as that's a search term. Can I use Egyptian god Anubis to indicate there's no reference to a specific brand?

Comment: Did you research the claim that "Anubis" is trademarked?  It certainly could be.  For example the word "Nike" is a trademark of Nike Corporation maker of sporting goods and so on.  You could certainly create an image of the Greek god Nike and put it on a T-shirt but I'm pretty sure Nike's lawyers would be after you if you put the word "Nike" on it as well.

Comment: What if didn't put the word on the t-shirt but in the description it said Anubis t-shirt. Or maybe Egyptian god Anubis t-shirt to clarify it's not the brand Anubis?

Comment: There is a word trademark on WIPO for section 25 - clothing, but I don't understand if that means used as a brand name or what

Comment: You might want to amend the question to add the "What ifs", especially if you expressly disclaim any association with the company holding the trademark on the name and are only using the name in its other meaning....not sure the answer myself

Comment: You might want to get a lawyer instead of randos on the internet.